# Laravel 7 Ajax Request variable is null

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel-7

I am posting some information to an ajax function the function is being called but the $Request is null. I will include the routes, controller and jQuery.

jQuery

```
$.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    })
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "/SubmitReview",
        contentType: "text",
        data: {
            Review: content,
            ImdbID: ImdbID
        },
        success : function(response){
            console.log("hello")
        },
        error: function(response){
            console.log("ajax error" + JSON.stringify(response))
        },
        dataType: 'json'
    });
```

Routes

```
Route::post('/SubmitReview', "ReviewController@SubmitReview");
```

Controller

```
public function SubmitReview(Request $Request)
    {
        $user = Auth::guard('User')->user();
        if ($user) {
            \Log::info($Request->all());
            \Log::info($Request->ImdbID);
            \Log::info($Request->input('ImdbID'));
            $ReviewObj = new Reviews();
            $ReviewObj->UserID = $user->id; //using guard
            $ReviewObj->ImdbID = $Request->input('ImdbID');
            $ReviewObj->Review = $Request->input('Review');
            $ReviewObj->Active = 0;
            $ReviewObj->save();
            
        }
        
    }
```

I've tried a few different methods but nothing has worked.

Comment: If you do a `dd($request)` above the `$user` what do you get? Did you _import_ the `Request` class?

Comment: yes I have included Request, and logging $Request returns nothing, ive also tried changing the data string but nothing seems to work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was due to content type: text when I remove this it works fine. Thanks for your help.